# How to call APP_INITIALIZER within angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

`APP_INITIALIZER` is called on app load and nothing should render before `APP_INITIALIZER` is resolved or rejected

This is working fine.

But on data change, I want to reinitialize the app with selected data , and need same functionality ( i.e nothing should render before `APP_INITIALIZER` is resolved or rejected )
how to do it?

How to reinitialize the app with data change?

Comment: First you need to understand what your goal to initialize it before app loading, Like I am load my config files before app start, so when config need to change you have to subscribe http call over the time to check if config has some changes if its changed then it just change the values of config file. let me know is it the same way you want it or not.

Comment: @AlokeT In my case if country changes, i have to change all the application data in accordance with that country –

Comment: @user3050267 can you post some code sample

Comment: @user3050267 I think you are going on wrong direction. Just made a generic accordance where any Country can be utilized as a base template... But if that's need to be done in your way you need to post some code examples to let us dive in and help you. :D

Answer (score 1):

After lots of thoughts and using best practised in my mind I can conclude you to use this approach instead of using config rewrite.

First you need to rewrite your base urls like this:

> http://localhost:4200/en/your/own/paths

The benefit of using this approach is when you load the config for your app you can use a country array as key value pair inside config file and push the specific country details there.

So after any component initialise you need to look into url for that country, and search that in config.country array if key of country found it used its values if not it will load the country data and pushed it.

You can implement a guard for this purpose or resolver for reusability of the code.

Let me know if it sound cool.